# Kendo Grid: Change columns order (event binding)

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using [Kendo UI for Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/) more specifically the Kendo Grid.

I would like to know if there is a way to notify the user each time the columns order change.

An example of what I'm looking for:

```
<kendo-grid 
    [data]="gridData"
    (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">
    (columnsOrderChanged)="columnsOrderChanged($event) //Something like this
</kendo-grid>
```

As you can see in the example above, I would like to achieve something similar to the [`sortChange`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/sorting/) approach for notifying each time the sort of a column is triggered.

Comment: [RTFM](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-columnreorder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what @R.Richards linked in the comment:

```
<kendo-grid 
    [data]="gridData"
    (sortChange)="sortChange($event)"
    [reorderable]="true"
    (columnReorder)="columnsOrderChanged($event)" >
</kendo-grid>
```

Keep in mind you need to enable column reorder.